# take first level of multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, multidimensional-array, laravel-5

so i am using [laravel kodeine](https://github.com/kodeine/laravel-acl/wiki/Get-Permissions) package for access control list and i got a problem with retrieving permission from the role.. it just have a different data form, from what i expected from laravel packages...

it come with array like this

```
array:4 [▼
  "artikel_view" => array:1 [▼
    "view" => true
  ]
  "artikel_create" => array:1 [▼
    "create" => true
  ]
  "artikel_update" => array:1 [▼
    "update" => true
  ]
  "artikel_destroy" => array:1 [▼
    "destroy" => true
  ]
]
```

so what i need is taking the first level like artikel_view, artikel_create, artikel_update, artikel_destroy

how to do that? i tried to do normal foreach loop but getting only the second level of array like view, create, update, destroy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$permissions = array(
  "artikel_view" => array(
    "view" => true
  ),
  "artikel_create" => array(
    "create" => true
  ),
  "artikel_update" => array(
    "update" => true
  ),
  "artikel_destroy" => array(
    "destroy" => true
  )
);

$perms = array_keys($permissions);

var_dump($perms);
```